# Longitude and Latitude from Google Maps Api JSON?

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I have this JSON from Google Maps API :

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Jakarta",
               "short_name" : "Jakarta",
               "types" : [ "colloquial_area", "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Special Capital Region of Jakarta",
               "short_name" : "Special Capital Region of Jakarta",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Indonesia",
               "short_name" : "ID",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Jakarta, Special Capital Region of Jakarta, Indonesia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -6.0886599,
                  "lng" : 106.972825
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -6.3708331,
                  "lng" : 106.686211
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -6.2087634,
               "lng" : 106.845599
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -6.0886599,
                  "lng" : 106.972825
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -6.3708331,
                  "lng" : 106.686211
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJnUvjRenzaS4RoobX2g-_cVM",
         "types" : [ "colloquial_area", "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

my question is, how to get this part from that JSON :

```
"location" : {
   "lat" : -6.2087634,
   "lng" : 106.845599
},
```

so that I can use it as PHP variable like this :

```
$lat = -6.2087634;
$lng = 106.845599;
```

and here's my JSON request to Google Maps API :

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=indonesia&key=MYKEY';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
```

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access it, do checks first:

```
if(isset($json['results'][0])) {
    $lat = $json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']; //-6.2087634
    $lng = $json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']; //106.845599
}
```